# How to pass data from Fragment B to A on popBackStack()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Fragment A ,B ,user navigates from A->B , and when clicks on button in Fragment B, it should navigate A.
How to pass data from Fragment B to A on popBackStack()?

Comment: popBackStack() itself doesn't provide a way to pass data, but there are many other ways. The best solution would depend on the type of data you are passing and the architecture of your app...

Comment: I need to pass int

Answer (score 0):

You might read [This Article](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

It defines how you could get two fragments to communicate.

Essentially, you would need to create an interface to implement in your activity, then pass that interface to your fragments. Call the interface method you need to update whatever data or state based on what the user clicked in your fragment, then use the same interface in the other fragment to retrieve data from the activity.